# Add user to phpbb3 forum user table from laravel

Tags: laravel-5, phpbb3, mybb

Laravel website user accounts creation and integration with phpbb3 forum

I am intergration phpbb3 to my existing laravel website. My requirement is to create user account in phpbb3 forum when user creates account on my existing website.... When I include the phpbb3 function file in my laravel add user method it says

```
Cannot redeclare redirect() (previously declared in D:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php:692)
```